# How to download apk file from webview without opening new browser

Tags: android

I have open an website links in webview .when i click on download of apk file a new browser is open.
Any can help me how can i download apk file without open the another browser

Comment: You can 'catch' the click and then download the apk yourself with a http client or invoking a download manager.

Comment: there are many apk file available in webpage link

Comment: I have successfully open the website link in webview, but when i download apk file then an new browser open and ask for download of apk file . i do not want to open the new browser , i want only that when i click on download then apk file download in background and an notification comes on background

Comment: Yes I already understood that. You are repeating yourself. Read my comment because I already told you how to download in background. Further `I have successfully open the website link in webview, but when i download apk file` is very confusing. Did you mean to tell: "i open the page in a webview but when the user clicks the apk link a browser is started" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dropbox for direct downlaod for example :

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xttkmuvu7hh72vu/MyFile.pdf
```

Becomes:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xttkmuvu7hh72vu/MyFile.pdf
```

Its just a url change , will work on any web app or android app

Comment: That will not prevent a WebView delegating those urls to a browser.

Comment: is that web page owned by u?

Comment: I have successfully open the website link in webview, but when i download apk file then an new browser open and ask for download of apk file . i do not want to open the new browser , i want only that when i click on download then apk file download in background and an notification comes on background.

Comment: this is web page ,which i have open

Comment: i understood the issue, but wanna know is that any webpage or ur builded webpage?